# I'm trying to create an html form to generate an url address based on input to a field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a small HTML document for my team to use to create fake devices for testing purposes in our program. We currently have a link to do this with but we have to manually change parts of it in the URL field before hitting enter to process it. I came up with the idea of creating this form so we can make sure that we are filling in all the elements of the URL correctly and then copy and paste the created URL into the browser. There are static parts of the address that we don't change and then there are values we update after the '=' sign. There are 4 different environments that we can use this in.

I admit it has been a while since I last worked in HTML so I've been trying to search forums and sites like W3School to find the segments of code that I think will serve the purpose I'm aiming for. The following code is where I have gotten so far but can't get it to work the way I've intended it to. If anyone can provide suggestions or feedback on what I missed or did wrong I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Item birth generator</title>
<script>
function mySubmit() {
    var addStart;
    var addPart1 = "part1=";
    var addPart2 = "&part2=";
    var addPart3 = "&part3=";
    var addPart4 = "&part4=";
    var addPart5 = "&part5=";
    var addPart6 = "&part6=";
    var addPart7 = "&part7=";
    var addPart8 = "&part8=";
    var myChoice = "choice";
    if (myChoice.value == "choice1")
        {addStart="https://address1?";}
    else if (myChoice.value == "choice2")
        {addStart="https://address2?";}
    else if (myChoice.value == "choice3")
        {addStart="https://address3?";}
    else (myChoice.value == "choice4")
        {addStart="https://address4?";}

    var address = addStart.concat(addPart1, "mInput1", addPart2, "mInput2", addPart3, "mInput3", addPart4, "mInput4", addPart5, "mInput5", addPart6, "mInput6", addPart7, "mInput7", addPart8, "mInput8");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = address;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<font> <H3>Please fill in the appropriate fields and then click Generate to create a url for an item in the chosen environment.</H3></font>
<form target="_self" id="demo" name="item" method="post" onSubmit="return checkValue();">
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="ch1" value="choice1" checked> Choice 1  <input type="radio" name ="choice" id="ch2" value="choice2"> Choice 2  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="ch3" value="choice3"> Choice 3  <input type="radio" name ="choice" id="ch4" value="choice4"> Choice 4
<br><br>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput1" maxlength="13"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 2</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 3</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 4</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput4"></td>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 5</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 6</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 7</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput7"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item Part 8</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mInput8"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Generate" onclick="mySubmit()"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="text" size="250" name="address" value=''>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to explain more specifically what you mean by "can't get it to work the way I've intended it to". It is a little hard for others to see in your question, exactly what you want, and what is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to get all of the elements to combine through concatenation to create essentially a website address that we can copy from the last text field named "address".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error with this line:

```
 var s.address = s.addStart.concat(addPart1, mInput1, addPart2, mInput2, addPart3, mInput3, addPart4, mInput4, addPart5, mInput5, addPart6, mInput6, addPart7, mInput7, addPart8, mInput8);
```

Verify what you are using is valid by testing the variables (output with a console.log or an alert) and check the command syntax. :)

Comment: I took your advice about using the console and found some of the issues I was overlooking in my code but it isn't grabbing the correct choice from the radio buttons (just taking the last one) and I'm still unable to get the values entered into the text fields. It generates the URL but rather than putting it into the empty address field like I expected it is clearing everything but the title from the page and place the URL under the title.

Comment: You need to ID the inputs in your HTML markup and grab the values that in javascript such as:

    id="mInput2" 

Then use:

    var thisInput = getElementById('mInput2').value;

However, the Radio Buttons are a separate issue, as well, and need a slightly different code to grab the 'selected' attribute.

Comment: I ID'd the input fields and got that working so now most of the concatenation is coming together. I've seen some suggestions for doing a loop for the radio buttons but I wasn't sure if I should create IDs for the different address headers and then call their identifier in the If/Then statement instead of how I have it now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I realized I was over-complicating things and changed value of the radio buttons to the address header I wanted then implemented a count to go through the radio buttons until it encounters one checked. Once it hits the checked button it grabs the value and passes it to the address header value and now it is creating the address the way I want it to.